# Capture mouse clicks and keyboard key strokes using C#

Tags: c#, keyboard-events, capture, mouseclick-event

I have a use case to capture mouse clicks and keyboard key strokes on a browser like IE using a C# program.

How can we do this ?

Thanks,
Gagan

Comment: I am pretty sure you need to use javascript for that. C# is a server side language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer lies in What you are actually trying to achieve?

If this is a KeyLogger - that should works across on applications - Read about SetWindowsHookEx.

If you are trying to automate some testing of a browser based app/website - then there are better frameworks like Selenium etc. which should be considered.

Comment: Simple C# keylogger using this method for the curious: https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/create-simple-hidden-console-keylogger-c-sharp-0132757/